# can't reformat my drive

Tags: format

when trying to reformat my drive to FAT to install a windows OS it comes up with "the device is busy /dev/sda1 is mounted" can anyone please give me any tips or guides on how to succesfully reformat my HDD?

Comment: Please clarify. What exactly have you done so far? How have you tried to format you drive?

Comment: The windows installer will take care of formatting.

Comment: it's windows vista and wont do it.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a USB key and then format your drive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to un-mount the drive first.  Boot from the Ubuntu CD or USB flash drive, or form within Ubuntu, if its a second drive, and use disks to do that.  Just type disks in Dash, when the window open up, click on the little square, to un-mount  as shown in the image below:

[image]

Once un-mounted, then you can format it, by clicking on the little gears, and choose Format.

[image]