# I can't format my USB flash

Tags: usb, format

I changed my Ubuntu 12.04 to 13.04 and now I want to format my USB flash when I right-click on my USB icon on Launcher.

I can see only 4 options:

1. Open
2. NEW VOLUME
3. Unlock from launcher
4. Eject.

There is no format option.
Thank You

Comment: Take a look at this [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/302402/cant-reformat-my-drive/302410#302410).

Answer (score 5):

Install gparted

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Open it and in the right corner select volume you want. Be careful! `/dev/sda` is most likely your hard drive. Use the drop-down arrow to switch to the USB drive. If you have more than one USB drive mounted, be sure you are choosing the correct one. Additional devices will be `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`, and so on.

Right click on the USB flash partition and you'll see format option. If it is grayed out, you need to unmount the USB drive first.